# Changing scale using TeXgraph

Tags: tikz-pgf, scaling

I'm using [TeXgraph](http://texgraph.tuxfamily.org/) to create figures and stuff, being a bit lazy and not wanting to code everything. I chose to export the code into `tikz`  to use with `tikzpicture`. The outcome is great if I don't have to scale anything, but when it comes to scaling, things aren't pretty.

I tried the built-in scale option of `tikzpicture` but this does not scale the text so it does not come out right. I then tried using the command `\pgftransformscale`, which got things a little better but it only gave me what I wanted, in terms of scaling when used in par with `\pgflowlevel`. However the placement is wrong and I have no idea how to move it. Here is a short example to see what I mean. First one is the original size, second one a smaller one with a half scale factor

```
Soit le graphique suivant: \\
% TeXgraph version 1.97
\begin{tikzpicture}%
%\pgflowlevel{\pgftransformscale{0.5}}
\useasboundingbox (-5.5,-5.5)--(5.5,5.5);
%objet6  (Utilisateur)
%objet1  (Grille)
\pgfsetstrokecolor{rgb,1:red,0.7529;green,0.7529;blue,0.7529}
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.4pt} 
\pgfsetroundjoin \pgfxyline(0,-5)(0,5)\pgfxyline(0.5,-5)(0.5,5)\pgfxyline(1,-5)    (1,5)\pgfxyline(1.5,-5)(1.5,5)
\pgfxyline(2,-5)(2,5)\pgfxyline(2.5,-5)(2.5,5)\pgfxyline(3,-5)(3,5)\pgfxyline(3.5,-5)(3.5,5)
\pgfxyline(4,-5)(4,5)\pgfxyline(4.5,-5)(4.5,5)\pgfxyline(5,-5)(5,5)\pgfxyline(-0.5,-5)(-0.5,5)
\pgfxyline(-1,-5)(-1,5)\pgfxyline(-1.5,-5)(-1.5,5)\pgfxyline(-2,-5)(-2,5)\pgfxyline(-2.5,-5)(-2.5,5)
\pgfxyline(-3,-5)(-3,5)\pgfxyline(-3.5,-5)(-3.5,5)\pgfxyline(-4,-5)(-4,5)\pgfxyline(-4.5,-5)(-4.5,5)
\pgfxyline(-5,-5)(-5,5)\pgfxyline(-5,0)(5,0)\pgfxyline(-5,0.5)(5,0.5)\pgfxyline(-5,1)(5,1)
\pgfxyline(-5,1.5)(5,1.5)\pgfxyline(-5,2)(5,2)\pgfxyline(-5,2.5)(5,2.5)\pgfxyline(-5,3)(5,3)
\pgfxyline(-5,3.5)(5,3.5)\pgfxyline(-5,4)(5,4)\pgfxyline(-5,4.5)(5,4.5)\pgfxyline(-5,5)(5,5)
\pgfxyline(-5,-0.5)(5,-0.5)\pgfxyline(-5,-1)(5,-1)\pgfxyline(-5,-1.5)(5,-1.5)\pgfxyline(-5,-2)(5,-2)
\pgfxyline(-5,-2.5)(5,-2.5)\pgfxyline(-5,-3)(5,-3)\pgfxyline(-5,-3.5)(5,-3.5)\pgfxyline(-5,-4)(5,-4)
\pgfxyline(-5,-4.5)(5,-4.5)\pgfxyline(-5,-5)(5,-5)
%objet2  (Axes)
\pgfsetstrokecolor{rgb,1:red,0;green,0;blue,0}
\pgfxyline(-5,0)(5,0)\pgfxyline(0,-5)(0,5)
\pgfsetfillcolor{rgb,1:red,0;green,0;blue,0}
\pgfxyline(0,-0.1)(0,0.1)\pgfxyline(1,-0.1)(1,0.1)\pgfxyline(2,-0.1)   (2,0.1)\pgfxyline(3,-0.1)(3,0.1)
\pgfxyline(4,-0.1)(4,0.1)\pgfxyline(5,-0.1)(5,0.1)
\pgfputat{\pgfxy(0.05,-0.2)}{\pgftext[top,left]{\small $0$}}
\pgfputat{\pgfxy(1,-0.2)}{\pgftext[top]{\small $1$}}
\pgfputat{\pgfxy(2,-0.2)}{\pgftext[top]{\small $2$}}
\pgfputat{\pgfxy(3,-0.2)}{\pgftext[top]{\small $3$}}
\pgfputat{\pgfxy(4,-0.2)}{\pgftext[top]{\small $4$}}
\pgfputat{\pgfxy(5,-0.2)}{\pgftext[top]{\small $5$}}
\pgfxyline(-1,-0.1)(-1,0.1)\pgfxyline(-2,-0.1)(-2,0.1)\pgfxyline(-3,-0.1)(-3,0.1)\pgfxyline(-4,-0.1)(-4,0.1)
\pgfxyline(-5,-0.1)(-5,0.1)
\pgfputat{\pgfxy(-1,-0.2)}{\pgftext[top]{\small $-1$}}
\pgfputat{\pgfxy(-2,-0.2)}{\pgftext[top]{\small $-2$}}
\pgfputat{\pgfxy(-3,-0.2)}{\pgftext[top]{\small $-3$}}
\pgfputat{\pgfxy(-4,-0.2)}{\pgftext[top]{\small $-4$}}
\pgfputat{\pgfxy(-5,-0.2)}{\pgftext[top]{\small $-5$}}
\pgfxyline(-0.1,0)(0.1,0)\pgfxyline(-0.1,1)(0.1,1)\pgfxyline(-0.1,2)(0.1,2)\pgfxyline(-0.1,3)(0.1,3)
\pgfxyline(-0.1,4)(0.1,4)\pgfxyline(-0.1,5)(0.1,5)
\pgfputat{\pgfxy(-0.2,0.05)}{\pgftext[right,bottom]{\small $0$}}
\pgfputat{\pgfxy(-0.2,1)}{\pgftext[right]{\small $1$}}
\pgfputat{\pgfxy(-0.2,2)}{\pgftext[right]{\small $2$}}
\pgfputat{\pgfxy(-0.2,3)}{\pgftext[right]{\small $3$}}
\pgfputat{\pgfxy(-0.2,4)}{\pgftext[right]{\small $4$}}
\pgfputat{\pgfxy(-0.2,5)}{\pgftext[right]{\small $5$}}
\pgfxyline(-0.1,-1)(0.1,-1)\pgfxyline(-0.1,-2)(0.1,-2)\pgfxyline(-0.1,-3)(0.1,-3)\pgfxyline(-0.1,-4)(0.1,-4)
\pgfxyline(-0.1,-5)(0.1,-5)
\pgfputat{\pgfxy(-0.2,-1)}{\pgftext[right]{\small $-1$}}
\pgfputat{\pgfxy(-0.2,-2)}{\pgftext[right]{\small $-2$}}
\pgfputat{\pgfxy(-0.2,-3)}{\pgftext[right]{\small $-3$}}
\pgfputat{\pgfxy(-0.2,-4)}{\pgftext[right]{\small $-4$}}
\pgfputat{\pgfxy(-0.2,-5)}{\pgftext[right]{\small $-5$}}
%D4  (Droite)
\pgfxyline(1,-5)(-5,1)
%D5  (Droite)
\pgfxyline(3,5)(-5,-3)
%objet5  (Droite)
\pgfxyline(-4,-5)(2.6667,5)
%bs  (Point(s))
\pgfsetstrokecolor{rgb,1:red,0;green,0;blue,1}
\pgfsetfillcolor{rgb,1:red,0;green,0;blue,1}\pgfellipse[fillstroke]{\pgfxy(0,2)}  {\pgfxy(0,0.0492)}{\pgfxy(-0.0492,0)}
\pgfellipse[fillstroke]{\pgfxy(0,1)}{\pgfxy(0,0.0492)}{\pgfxy(-0.0492,0)}
\pgfellipse[fillstroke]{\pgfxy(0,-4)}{\pgfxy(0,0.0492)}{\pgfxy(-0.0492,0)}
\pgfputat{\pgfxy(-4,1)}{\pgftext{\color{rgb,1:red,0;green,0;blue,0}\small   $D4$}}\pgfstroke
\pgfputat{\pgfxy(-1,1.5)}{\pgftext{\color{rgb,1:red,0;green,0;blue,0}\small $D5$}}\pgfstroke
\pgfputat{\pgfxy(0.5,1)}{\pgftext{\color{rgb,1:red,0;green,0;blue,0}\small   $D6$}}\pgfstroke
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

And for the scaled one

```
Soit le graphique suivant: \\
% TeXgraph version 1.97
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\pgflowlevel{\pgftransformscale{0.5}}
\useasboundingbox (-5.5,-5.5)--(5.5,5.5);
%objet6  (Utilisateur)
%objet1  (Grille)
\pgfsetstrokecolor{rgb,1:red,0.7529;green,0.7529;blue,0.7529}
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.4pt} 
\pgfsetroundjoin \pgfxyline(0,-5)(0,5)\pgfxyline(0.5,-5)(0.5,5)\pgfxyline(1,-5)    (1,5)\pgfxyline(1.5,-5)(1.5,5)
\pgfxyline(2,-5)(2,5)\pgfxyline(2.5,-5)(2.5,5)\pgfxyline(3,-5)(3,5)\pgfxyline(3.5,-5)(3.5,5)
\pgfxyline(4,-5)(4,5)\pgfxyline(4.5,-5)(4.5,5)\pgfxyline(5,-5)(5,5)\pgfxyline(-0.5,-5)(-0.5,5)
\pgfxyline(-1,-5)(-1,5)\pgfxyline(-1.5,-5)(-1.5,5)\pgfxyline(-2,-5)(-2,5)\pgfxyline(-2.5,-5)(-2.5,5)
\pgfxyline(-3,-5)(-3,5)\pgfxyline(-3.5,-5)(-3.5,5)\pgfxyline(-4,-5)(-4,5)\pgfxyline(-4.5,-5)(-4.5,5)
\pgfxyline(-5,-5)(-5,5)\pgfxyline(-5,0)(5,0)\pgfxyline(-5,0.5)(5,0.5)\pgfxyline(-5,1)(5,1)
\pgfxyline(-5,1.5)(5,1.5)\pgfxyline(-5,2)(5,2)\pgfxyline(-5,2.5)(5,2.5)\pgfxyline(-5,3)(5,3)
\pgfxyline(-5,3.5)(5,3.5)\pgfxyline(-5,4)(5,4)\pgfxyline(-5,4.5)(5,4.5)\pgfxyline(-5,5)(5,5)
\pgfxyline(-5,-0.5)(5,-0.5)\pgfxyline(-5,-1)(5,-1)\pgfxyline(-5,-1.5)(5,-1.5)\pgfxyline(-5,-2)(5,-2)
\pgfxyline(-5,-2.5)(5,-2.5)\pgfxyline(-5,-3)(5,-3)\pgfxyline(-5,-3.5)(5,-3.5)\pgfxyline(-5,-4)(5,-4)
\pgfxyline(-5,-4.5)(5,-4.5)\pgfxyline(-5,-5)(5,-5)
%objet2  (Axes)
\pgfsetstrokecolor{rgb,1:red,0;green,0;blue,0}
\pgfxyline(-5,0)(5,0)\pgfxyline(0,-5)(0,5)
\pgfsetfillcolor{rgb,1:red,0;green,0;blue,0}
\pgfxyline(0,-0.1)(0,0.1)\pgfxyline(1,-0.1)(1,0.1)\pgfxyline(2,-0.1)   (2,0.1)\pgfxyline(3,-0.1)(3,0.1)
\pgfxyline(4,-0.1)(4,0.1)\pgfxyline(5,-0.1)(5,0.1)
\pgfputat{\pgfxy(0.05,-0.2)}{\pgftext[top,left]{\small $0$}}
\pgfputat{\pgfxy(1,-0.2)}{\pgftext[top]{\small $1$}}
\pgfputat{\pgfxy(2,-0.2)}{\pgftext[top]{\small $2$}}
\pgfputat{\pgfxy(3,-0.2)}{\pgftext[top]{\small $3$}}
\pgfputat{\pgfxy(4,-0.2)}{\pgftext[top]{\small $4$}}
\pgfputat{\pgfxy(5,-0.2)}{\pgftext[top]{\small $5$}}
\pgfxyline(-1,-0.1)(-1,0.1)\pgfxyline(-2,-0.1)(-2,0.1)\pgfxyline(-3,-0.1)(-3,0.1)\pgfxyline(-4,-0.1)(-4,0.1)
\pgfxyline(-5,-0.1)(-5,0.1)
\pgfputat{\pgfxy(-1,-0.2)}{\pgftext[top]{\small $-1$}}
\pgfputat{\pgfxy(-2,-0.2)}{\pgftext[top]{\small $-2$}}
\pgfputat{\pgfxy(-3,-0.2)}{\pgftext[top]{\small $-3$}}
\pgfputat{\pgfxy(-4,-0.2)}{\pgftext[top]{\small $-4$}}
\pgfputat{\pgfxy(-5,-0.2)}{\pgftext[top]{\small $-5$}}
\pgfxyline(-0.1,0)(0.1,0)\pgfxyline(-0.1,1)(0.1,1)\pgfxyline(-0.1,2)(0.1,2)\pgfxyline(-0.1,3)(0.1,3)
\pgfxyline(-0.1,4)(0.1,4)\pgfxyline(-0.1,5)(0.1,5)
\pgfputat{\pgfxy(-0.2,0.05)}{\pgftext[right,bottom]{\small $0$}}
\pgfputat{\pgfxy(-0.2,1)}{\pgftext[right]{\small $1$}}
\pgfputat{\pgfxy(-0.2,2)}{\pgftext[right]{\small $2$}}
\pgfputat{\pgfxy(-0.2,3)}{\pgftext[right]{\small $3$}}
\pgfputat{\pgfxy(-0.2,4)}{\pgftext[right]{\small $4$}}
\pgfputat{\pgfxy(-0.2,5)}{\pgftext[right]{\small $5$}}
\pgfxyline(-0.1,-1)(0.1,-1)\pgfxyline(-0.1,-2)(0.1,-2)\pgfxyline(-0.1,-3)(0.1,-3)\pgfxyline(-0.1,-4)(0.1,-4)
\pgfxyline(-0.1,-5)(0.1,-5)
\pgfputat{\pgfxy(-0.2,-1)}{\pgftext[right]{\small $-1$}}
\pgfputat{\pgfxy(-0.2,-2)}{\pgftext[right]{\small $-2$}}
\pgfputat{\pgfxy(-0.2,-3)}{\pgftext[right]{\small $-3$}}
\pgfputat{\pgfxy(-0.2,-4)}{\pgftext[right]{\small $-4$}}
\pgfputat{\pgfxy(-0.2,-5)}{\pgftext[right]{\small $-5$}}
%D4  (Droite)
\pgfxyline(1,-5)(-5,1)
%D5  (Droite)
\pgfxyline(3,5)(-5,-3)
%objet5  (Droite)
\pgfxyline(-4,-5)(2.6667,5)
%bs  (Point(s))
\pgfsetstrokecolor{rgb,1:red,0;green,0;blue,1}
\pgfsetfillcolor{rgb,1:red,0;green,0;blue,1}\pgfellipse[fillstroke]{\pgfxy(0,2)}  {\pgfxy(0,0.0492)}{\pgfxy(-0.0492,0)}
\pgfellipse[fillstroke]{\pgfxy(0,1)}{\pgfxy(0,0.0492)}{\pgfxy(-0.0492,0)}
\pgfellipse[fillstroke]{\pgfxy(0,-4)}{\pgfxy(0,0.0492)}{\pgfxy(-0.0492,0)}
\pgfputat{\pgfxy(-4,1)}{\pgftext{\color{rgb,1:red,0;green,0;blue,0}\small   $D4$}}\pgfstroke
\pgfputat{\pgfxy(-1,1.5)}{\pgftext{\color{rgb,1:red,0;green,0;blue,0}\small $D5$}}\pgfstroke
\pgfputat{\pgfxy(0.5,1)}{\pgftext{\color{rgb,1:red,0;green,0;blue,0}\small   $D6$}}\pgfstroke
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

I'd like to know if there would be a way to move the rendered object, or another way of scaling that would do it by itself.

Comment: I don't see any unscaled text. Which text exactly is that you see unscaled?

Comment: With the combination of pgflowlevel and transform scale, the text is scaled all right but the placement of the figure is wrong, I'd like to be able to move it.

Answer (score 2):

You can get away with a proper picture by using the scale a little differently. So change the scaled picture's initial line with the following.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center),transform canvas={scale around={0.5:(5,-5)}}]% <- Changed
```

But I think laziness is not a valid excuse as you have experienced that there is no control over the resulting picture hence it takes more effort. In fact, it's quite simple to do it via [`pgfplots`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\noindent Soit le graphique suivant:

\begin{tikzpicture}[mydot/.style={blue,inner sep=1pt,fill,circle}]
\begin{axis}[no marks,
xmin=-5,xmax=5,
ymin=-5,ymax=5,
grid=both,
axis lines=middle,
axis line style={-|},
xtick={-5,...,5},
ytick={-5,...,5},
minor tick num=1,
x=1cm,y=1cm
]
\addplot {x+2};
\addplot {1.5*x+1};
\addplot {-x-4};
\node[mydot] at (axis cs:0,1) {};
\node[mydot] at (axis cs:0,2) {};
\node[mydot] at (axis cs:0,-4) {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]